# VHDL code for Tic tac toe game?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, tic-tac-toe

I have 18 output and 9 push switches to work with and one led as output which changing its states each time the push button is pressed to automate the chance of two players. my code is not working, pls help
my code is...expected behavour is that when momentarily in1 switch is high then play_to_play should toggle on each event of the inputs and according to play_to_play status and in1 high either ou11 or ou21 should go high i.e one player has played his chance and automatically at the next event it takes that it is player 2 chance

```
library IEEE;   
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;  
entity TicTac is     
    Port ( in1 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           in2 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           in3 : in  STD_LOGIC;   
           in4 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           in5 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           in6 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           in7 : in  STD_LOGIC;   
           in8 : in  STD_LOGIC;   
           in9 : in  STD_LOGIC;   
              reset : in  STD_LOGIC;  
            p_to_play : out STD_Logic;   
           p1_win : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           p2_win : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou11 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou12 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou13 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou14 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou15 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou16 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou17 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou18 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou19 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou21 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou22 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou23 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou24 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou25 : out  STD_LOGIC;  
           ou26 : out  STD_LOGIC;  
           ou27 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou28 : out  STD_LOGIC;   
           ou29 : out  STD_LOGIC);   
end TicTac;   
architecture Behavioral of TicTac is   
Signal temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6,temp7, temp8, temp9,p1_play :std_logic :='0';    
signal o11,o12,o13,o14,o15,o16,o17,o18,o19,o21,o22,o23,o24,o25,o26,o27,o28,o29 :std_logic :='0';    
signal p1win,p2win :std_logic :='0';    
begin   
process(in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7,in8,in9,reset)
begin  

   if ((in1'event or in2'event or in3'event or in4'event or in5'event or in6'event or in7'event or in8'event or in9'event) and
    (in1='1' or in2 ='1' or in3='1' or in4='1' or in5='1' or in6='1' or in7='1' or in8='1' or in9='1')) then     
      p1_play <= not(p1_play);    
if(reset'event and reset= '1') then  
temp1 <='0';    
temp2 <='0';   
temp3 <='0';   
temp4 <='0';   
temp5 <='0';   
temp6 <='0';   
temp7 <='0';   
temp8 <='0';  
temp9 <='0';   
p1_play <= '0';  
p1win <='0';    
p2win <='0';    
o11 <='0';    
o12 <='0';   
o13 <='0';   
o14 <='0';   
o15 <='0';   
o16 <='0';   
o17 <='0';   
o18 <='0';   
o19 <='0';   
o21 <='0';   
o22 <='0';   
o23 <='0';   
o24 <='0';   
o25 <='0';   
o26 <='0';   
o27 <='0';   
o28 <='0';   
o29 <='0';   
end if;     
if(in1= '1') then   
temp1 <='1';   
end if;  
if(in2= '1') then   
temp2 <='1';   
end if;   
if(in3= '1') then
temp3 <='1';
end if;
if(in4= '1') then
temp1 <='1';
end if;
if(in5= '1') then
temp5 <='1';
end if;
if(in6= '1') then
temp6 <='1';
end if;
if(in7= '1') then
temp7 <='1';
end if;
if(in8= '1') then
temp8 <='1';
end if;
if(in9= '1') then
temp9 <='1';  
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp1='1') then    
o11 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp2='1') then   
o12 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp3='1') then
o13 <= '1';    
end if;   
if(p1_play='0' and temp4='1') then
o14 <= '1';   
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp5='1') then
o15 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp6='1') then
o16 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp7='1') then
o17 <= '1';   
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp8='1') then
o18 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='0' and temp9='1') then
o19 <= '1';    
end if;     
if(p1_play='1' and temp1='1') then
o21 <= '1';    
end if;   
if(p1_play='1' and temp2='1') then
o22 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='1' and temp3='1') then
o23 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='1' and temp4='1') then
o24 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='1' and temp5='1') then
o25 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='1' and temp6='1') then
o26 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='1' and temp7='1') then
o27 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='1' and temp8='1') then
o28 <= '1';    
end if;    
if(p1_play='1' and temp9='1') then
o29 <= '1';    
end if;    
if((o11='1' and o12='1' and o13='1') or (o14='1' and o15='1' and o16='1') or (o17='1' and o18='1' and o19='1')
or (o11='1' and o14='1' and o17='1') or (o12='1' and o15='1' and o18='1') or (o13='1' and o16='1' and o19='1')
or (o11='1' and o15='1' and o19='1') or (o13='1' and o15='1' and o17='1')) then
p1win <='1';    
end if;     
if((o21='1' and o22='1' and o23='1') or (o24='1' and o25='1' and o26='1') or (o27='1' and o28='1' and o29='1')
or (o21='1' and o24='1' and o27='1') or (o22='1' and o25='1' and o28='1') or (o23='1' and o26='1' and o29='1')
or (o21='1' and o25='1' and o29='1') or (o23='1' and o25='1' and o27='1')) then
p2win <='1';     
end if;   
end if;   
end process;   
ou11 <= o11;   
ou12 <= o12;   
ou13 <= o13;   
ou14 <= o14;   
ou15 <= o15;   
ou16 <= o16;   
ou17 <= o17;   

    ou18 <= o18;   
    ou19 <= o19;   
    ou21 <= o21;  
    ou22 <= o22;   
    ou23 <= o23;   
    ou24 <= o24;  
    ou25 <= o25;   
    ou26 <= o26;   
    ou27 <= o27;   
    ou28 <= o28;   
    ou29 <= o29;   
    p_to_play <= p1_play;   
    p1_win <= p1win;   
    p2_win <= p2win;   
    end Behavior

al;
```

Comment: Please be more specific.  What about it is not working?   What do you do?  What's the expected behavior?

Comment: as Russell said, be more specific in what is not working. however, one thing that is for sure not optimal is, that you have nested event sensitivities... I'd guess, that you'd be better off if you have something like >>> if reset='1' then... ELSIF((in1'event...)) then... end if; <<< like that, you don't have nested sensitivities. In addition, i think you should read about the difference of "variable" and "signal" in VHDL and then check, whether your code as you expected it to be ;-)

Comment: when i checking usin test bench....when in1 switch momentarily goes high, at the same time temp1 also goes high acoording to the program but at the same time ou11 or ou12 should go high but this one is not going high instead it is going high in the next clock cycle of in1 it is going high..please help

Comment: You produce a _lot_ of code for a simple 3x3 game. Try to use arrays and loops instead of enumerating all possibilities. What if somebody came up with a 4x4 version? What about a 10x10 version?

Comment: Simple game but output is not what expected....please can u write the code for me according to my harware...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes in VHDL are **not** the same as processes on a regular programming language. All signal assignments within a process actually occur at the time the process completes (actually a delta time later, which is basically a 0 time difference). Since you are trying to use the value of temp that you just assigned earlier in the process, but it hasn't actually been written yet, you are not triggering your if statement until the next time the process runs.

As an aside, I didn't notice any mechanism to prevent players from playing in spaces that they or their opponent already played.

EDIT: Also, what do you plan to do with this? If you want to put it on a real FPGA with real switches it likely won't work because of an electromechanical phenomenon called switch bouncing that makes each press of a switch seem like many to the hardware.

EDIT2: To fix this (still won't fix switch bouncing) you may want to scrap temp entirely (replacing it with the "in" signals) and put the entire contents of the process, except the reset stuff, inside your if statement that detects rising edges on the in signals.

EDIT3: Here is a VHDL model for a 4x4 tic-tac-toe board with your hardware setup expanded to the 16 squares of a 4x4 board. See if you can understand what is done and why, then adapt it to a 3x3 board.

```
library IEEE;   
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;  
entity TicTac is   
    Port (button : in  std_logic_vector(16 downto 1);  
          reset : in  std_logic;  
          p_to_play : out std_logic;   
          p1_win : out  std_logic := '0';   
          p2_win : out  std_logic := '0';   
          ou1 : out std_logic_vector(16 downto 1);    
          ou2 : out std_logic_vector(16 downto 1));   
end TicTac;   
architecture Behavioral of TicTac is    

    signal o1 : std_logic_vector(16 downto 1) := (others => '0');    
    signal o2 : std_logic_vector(16 downto 1) := (others => '0'); 
    signal o  : std_logic_vector(16 downto 1) := (others => '0');
    signal p  : std_logic;
    signal win  : std_logic;
    signal win1 : std_logic;
    signal win2 : std_logic; 

begin   
    ou1 <= o1;
    ou2 <= o2;
    p_to_play <= p;
    p1_win <= win1;
    p2_win <= win2;
    win <= win1 or win2;

    gen_spots : for i in 1 to 16 generate --3 flip flops share a clock (button) for every space on the board
        process(button(i), reset)
        begin
            if(reset = '1') then
                o(i)  <= '0';
                o1(i) <= '0';
                o2(i) <= '0';
            elsif(button(i)'event and button(i)='1' and o(i)='0' and win='0') then
                o(i) <= '1';
                if (p = '0') then
                    o1(i) <= '1';
                else
                    o2(i) <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
    end generate gen_spots;

    process(o) --determines current player by xoring the o values together.
        variable ot : std_logic;
    begin
        ot := '0';
        for i in 1 to 16 loop
            ot := ot xor o(i);
        end loop;
        p <= ot;
    end process;

    process(o1) --checks if player 1 wins
    begin
        win1 <= '0'; --only happens if none of the win1 <= '1' statements occur
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            if (o1(1+i*4)='1' and o1(2+i*4)='1' and o1(3+i*4)='1' and o1(4+i*4)='1') then --rows
                win1 <= '1';
            end if;
            if (o1(1+i)='1' and o1(5+i)='1' and o1(9+i)='1' and o1(13+i)='1') then --columns
                win1 <= '1';
            end if;
        end loop;
        if (o1(1)='1' and o1(6)='1' and o1(11)='1' and o1(16)='1') or (o1(4)='1' and o1(7)='1' and o1(10)='1' and o1(13)='1') then --diagonals
            win1 <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;

    process(o2) --checks if player 2 wins
    begin
        win2 <= '0'; --only happens if none of the win2 <= '1' statements occur
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            if (o2(1+i*4)='1' and o2(2+i*4)='1' and o2(3+i*4)='1' and o2(4+i*4)='1') then --rows
                win2 <= '1';
            end if;
            if (o2(1+i)='1' and o2(5+i)='1' and o2(9+i)='1' and o2(13+i)='1') then --columns
                win2 <= '1';
            end if;
        end loop;
        if (o2(1)='1' and o2(6)='1' and o2(11)='1' and o2(16)='1') or (o2(4)='1' and o2(7)='1' and o2(10)='1' and o2(13)='1') then --diagonals
            win2 <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I haven't done exhaustive tests, but this compiles and works for a couple test cases.

Please remember to mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I have got a Push type micro switch as my input hardware...when the switch is pressed it will give logic 1...if not what is the method to do it....????

Comment: if I completely remove temp if i am pressing in1 then how can i get constatnt ou11 even if in1 is lowered

Comment: The way you have your program set up, the ou values are only affected when a rising edge on one of the in signals occurs. Moreover, you never set any ou value back to '0' except in the reset statement. That means that once you set an ou value to '1' it can never return to '0' until you reset the system.

Comment: As for push type microswitches, they are absolutely affected by switch bounce. For this particular game, since once an input has been pressed once (for either player) it can never be valid again, you can avoid the problems from switch bouncing by implementing logic to ignore keypresses on already activated squares.

Comment: thanks a lot @QuantumRipple for your help... I got what you did and just simply love your logics... ☺☺☺

Answer (score 0):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------   TICTAC TOE GAME ------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity cs_main is
    Port ( in1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
            in2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              in3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
                  in4 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              in5 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              in6 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              in7 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              in8 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              in9 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           output1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
              output2 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
              chance_real : out  STD_LOGIC;
              wing : out  STD_LOGIC;
              winr : out  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC);
end cs_main;

architecture Behavioral of cs_main is
signal temp1,out1,out2,out11,out22 :std_logic_vector (8 downto 0):= "000000000";
signal chance : std_logic := '0';
signal wing1,winr1 : std_logic := '0';
begin

tictac :process(in1,in2,in3,in4,in5,in6,in7,in8,in9)
begin

if rising_edge (reset) then
  out1 <= "000000000";
  out2 <= "000000000";
  chance <= '0';
  wing1 <= '0';
  winr1 <= '0';
else
 if (wing1 = '0' and winr1 = '0') then 
  if rising_edge (in1) then
   if (chance = '0') then
     out1 <= "000000001";
   elsif(chance = '1') then
     out2 <= "000000001";
   end if;
   chance <= not chance ;
  elsif rising_edge(in2) then
   if (chance = '0') then
     out1 <= "000000010";
   elsif(chance = '1') then
     out2 <= "000000010";
   end if;
   chance <= not chance ;
  elsif rising_edge(in3) then
   if (chance = '0') then
     out1 <= "000000100";
   elsif(chance = '1') then
     out2 <= "000000100";
   end if;
  chance <= not chance ;
 elsif rising_edge(in4) then
  if (chance = '0') then
    out1 <= "000001000";
  elsif(chance = '1') then
    out2 <= "000001000";
  end if;
  chance <= not chance ;
 elsif rising_edge(in5) then
  if (chance = '0') then
    out1 <= "000010000";
  elsif(chance = '1') then
    out2 <= "000010000";
  end if;
  chance <= not chance ;
 elsif rising_edge(in6) then
  if (chance = '0') then
    out1 <= "000100000";
  elsif(chance = '1') then
    out2 <= "000100000";
  end if;
  chance <= not chance ;
 elsif rising_edge(in7) then
  if (chance = '0') then
    out1 <= "001000000";
  elsif(chance = '1') then
    out2 <= "001000000";
  end if;
  chance <= not chance ;
 elsif rising_edge(in8) then
  if (chance = '0') then
    out1 <= "010000000";
  elsif(chance = '1') then
    out2 <= "010000000";
  end if;
  chance <= not chance ;
 elsif rising_edge(in9) then
  if (chance = '0') then
    out1 <= "100000000";
  elsif(chance = '1') then
    out2 <= "100000000";
  end if;
  chance <= not chance ;
 end if;
end if;

  out11 <= out11 or out1;
  out22 <= out22 or out2;

 if(((out11 = "000000111" or out11 = "000111000" or out11 = "111000000" or
    out11 = "001001001" or out11 = "010010010" or out11 = "100100100" or
    out11 = "100010001" or out11 = "001010100" ) and chance ='0') or
    ((out22 = "000000111" or out22 = "000111000" or out22 = "111000000" or
    out22 = "001001001" or out22 = "010010010" or out22 = "100100100" or
    out22 = "100010001" or out22 = "001010100" ) and chance = '1')) then
   if (chance = '0')then
    wing1 <= '1';
    winr1 <= '0';
   elsif (chance = '1') then
    wing1 <= '0';
    winr1 <= '1';
   end if;
 else
    wing1 <= '0';
    winr1 <= '0';
 end if;
end if;

end process tictac;

  output1 <= out11 ;
  output2 <= out22 ;  
  chance_real <=  chance;
  wing <= wing1;
  winr <= winr1;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code compiled without an error on my QUARTUS II version 15 software. i programmed it on my ALTERA DE2 FPGA BOARD but it does not display on the monitor. can anyone tell me what to do please

```
library IEEE;   
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;  
entity TicTac is   
    Port (button : in  std_logic_vector(16 downto 1);  
          reset : in  std_logic;  
          p_to_play : out std_logic;   
          p1_win : out  std_logic := '0';   
          p2_win : out  std_logic := '0';   
          ou1 : out std_logic_vector(16 downto 1);    
          ou2 : out std_logic_vector(16 downto 1));   
end TicTac;   
architecture Behavioral of TicTac is    

    signal o1 : std_logic_vector(16 downto 1) := (others => '0');    
    signal o2 : std_logic_vector(16 downto 1) := (others => '0'); 
    signal o  : std_logic_vector(16 downto 1) := (others => '0');
    signal p  : std_logic;
    signal win  : std_logic;
    signal win1 : std_logic;
    signal win2 : std_logic; 

begin   
    ou1 <= o1;
    ou2 <= o2;
    p_to_play <= p;
    p1_win <= win1;
    p2_win <= win2;
    win <= win1 or win2;

    gen_spots : for i in 1 to 16 generate --3 flip flops share a clock (button) for every space on the board
        process(button(i), reset)
        begin
            if(reset = '1') then
                o(i)  <= '0';
                o1(i) <= '0';
                o2(i) <= '0';
            elsif(button(i)'event and button(i)='1' and o(i)='0' and win='0') then
                o(i) <= '1';
                if (p = '0') then
                    o1(i) <= '1';
                else
                    o2(i) <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
    end generate gen_spots;

    process(o) --determines current player by xoring the o values together.
        variable ot : std_logic;
    begin
        ot := '0';
        for i in 1 to 16 loop
            ot := ot xor o(i);
        end loop;
        p <= ot;
    end process;

    process(o1) --checks if player 1 wins
    begin
        win1 <= '0'; --only happens if none of the win1 <= '1' statements occur
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            if (o1(1+i*4)='1' and o1(2+i*4)='1' and o1(3+i*4)='1' and o1(4+i*4)='1') then --rows
                win1 <= '1';
            end if;
            if (o1(1+i)='1' and o1(5+i)='1' and o1(9+i)='1' and o1(13+i)='1') then --columns
                win1 <= '1';
            end if;
        end loop;
        if (o1(1)='1' and o1(6)='1' and o1(11)='1' and o1(16)='1') or (o1(4)='1' and o1(7)='1' and o1(10)='1' and o1(13)='1') then --diagonals
            win1 <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;

    process(o2) --checks if player 2 wins
    begin
        win2 <= '0'; --only happens if none of the win2 <= '1' statements occur
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            if (o2(1+i*4)='1' and o2(2+i*4)='1' and o2(3+i*4)='1' and o2(4+i*4)='1') then --rows
                win2 <= '1';
            end if;
            if (o2(1+i)='1' and o2(5+i)='1' and o2(9+i)='1' and o2(13+i)='1') then --columns
                win2 <= '1';
            end if;
        end loop;
        if (o2(1)='1' and o2(6)='1' and o2(11)='1' and o2(16)='1') or (o2(4)='1' and o2(7)='1' and o2(10)='1' and o2(13)='1') then --diagonals
            win2 <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: who has an idea about the VGA display and how this code should work please. am really new to VHDL